# Why am I seeing webmin in lsof output?

Tags: linux, networking

I am running a server application (written in C), that is bound to my server on `localhost` address `127.0.0.1` and let it listen in first case on port `10000` and in second case on port `20000`

When I run command I `lsof | grep IP` in last column is:

- localhost:**webmin** (LISTEN) (first case)
- localhost:20000 (LISTEN)  (second case)

So instead of port `10000` there is `webmin`.

What does this mean? I found [this](http://webmin.com/).

It says that Webmin is a web-based interface for system administration for Unix. This doesn't help me; **why am I seeing `webmin` in my port list**?

Comment: It means it's "a well known port"

Comment: It sounds like your system thinks port 10000 is a "well-known port" used by this webmin server, and is using the string `webmin` as an alias for that port number...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

webmin is associated with port 10000. lsof is "deducing" that webmin is what is running. For instance, if your app was bound to port 3306, lsof would think it was MySQL.

See [this Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) for a list of well-known ports.

Comment: `lsof` **is not deducing** that webmin is running. It just replaces the numeric representation of the port with the human readable format of the port/service found in `/etc/services` unless you call lsof with the `-n` option.

Comment: Yes.... which is a form of deduction, for some meaning of that word.

Comment: Anthropomorphizing system processes is a sign of not understanding what is actually occurring.

Comment: That's why "deducing" is in quotes in my reply. For some definition of the word, it *is* "deducing", even if only via naive substitution of values in an attempt to make its output more understandable to you, the user.

Answer (score 13):

It basically means that port 10000 is assocsiated with webmin in your `/etc/services` file.

Comment: @user1097772, just so you know, this is the file where the "well known" ports mentioned by others are defined.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers nope, but I know it since now :] thx ;)